# i am trying room database using android kotlin and it will give error : UNIQUE constraint failed: favorite.id (code 1555 SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_PRIMARYKEY)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

i am trying room database using android kotlin and it will give error : UNIQUE constraint failed: favorite.id (code 1555 SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_PRIMARYKEY)
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: favorite.id (code 1555 SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_PRIMARYKEY)

any solution

Answer (score 0):

It means the DB has a unique constraint on the field id.  Each value needs to be unique.  You're trying to upload a row with an id that already exists.